# visual code type script shows error on whitespace and tslint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual code and It really annoying to see the red dashed line on each sentence because whitespace or tslint qoutemark.
I tried to install typescript globally but nothing changed.
how can i disable it? 
[image]

Comment: You're typing sentences into a TypeScript file?

Comment: Yes. I edited my post you can see the photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of all TSLint errors, uninstall or disable the TSLint extension.

[image]

In other words, open the Extensions view, search for tslint, click on the gear icon, and then choose the appropriate selection.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options here:

- **Disable the rules** -> Put the cursor on the error, and click the lamp on the gutter.
- **Change the rules**  -> Edit your [tslint.json](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/)
- **Follow the rules**  -> Best! Click `Ctrl-.` for auto fix.

Comment: Option 2 - how i change the rules?

Comment: Added a link to the tslint config.